# Insert string in RichTextBox at cursor position

Tags: c#, string, richtextbox

I'm trying to insert a string at the cursor's position.. I'm writing a syntax highlighter control and I'm wanting to make a function so the user can comment out a line of code. "// blah" all this would do is insert the specified comment identifier..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
richTextBox1.SelectedText = "//";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
richTextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(Point point)
```

Will give you the character index.

Another method that could help you:

```
richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(int lineNumber);
richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
richTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(int index);
```